# Performance Tuning SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following sql. When I check the execution plan of this query we observe an index scan. How do I replace it with index seek. I have non clustered index on IdDeleted column.[image: Execution Plan]

```
SELECT Cast(Format(Sum(COALESCE(InstalledSubtotal, 0)), 'F') AS MONEY) AS TotalSoldNet,
       BP.BoundProjectId                                               AS ProjectId
FROM   BoundProducts BP
WHERE  BP.IsDeleted=0 or BP.IsDeleted is null
GROUP  BY BP.BoundProjectId
```

I tried like this and got index seek, but the result was wrong.

```
SELECT Cast(Format(Sum(COALESCE(InstalledSubtotal, 0)), 'F') AS MONEY) AS TotalSoldNet,
       BP.BoundProjectId                                               AS ProjectId
FROM   BoundProducts BP
WHERE  BP.IsDeleted=0
GROUP  BY BP.BoundProjectId
```

Can anyone kindly suggest me to get the right result set with index seek.

I mean how to I replace (BP.IsDeleted=0 or BP.IsDeleted is null) condition to make use of index seek.

Edit, added row counts from comments of one of the answers:

```
null: 254962 rows
0:    392002 rows
1:     50211 rows
```

Comment: my index definition has two columns (BoundProjectId, IsDeleted). I want to change this to an Index seek instead of Index scan.

Comment: One possibility is to make two queries, one for each condition, and `UNION` them together

Comment: @HoneyBadger Might not be the best option, since you'd be scanning the table twice.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, that's true. I was just throwing in a possible option.

Comment: Yes @Radu, Kindly compare the query cost. I would prefer Index seek.

Comment: why can't you modify it as ISNULL(BP.IsDeleted,0) = 0

Comment: Updating table statistics, maybe?

Comment: Usually when I'm checking if a value is null or 0 I would use `ISNULL(BP.IsDeleted, 0) = 0`. But in this case it might not make any difference...

Comment: @Jonathan I suspect it would bypass the index if adding the function over the column.

Comment: Always be careful about trying to outsmart the database engine.  If it picked an index scan over an index seek, it's because it compared the cost of both and determined that in this case there would be no gain in using a seek *for the data you are trying to fetch in this case*.  Do you have any reason to doubt that it's right?

Comment: I tried with this approach but there is no change in the execution plan. It is better only for readability.

Comment: A scan can outperform a seek, particularly on smaller sets where there is a high number of rows matching the is null predicate

Comment: Just a note, you should try to avoid using format if possible, it's also quite heavy operation: http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Comment: FYI using `ISNULL(BP.IsDeleted,0)` would always prevent an index seek.

Comment: @Alex: Is any another approach to utilize Index seek

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about how many rows there are (zeros and nulls) in the table. The arrow width in the query plan for the scan is quite big, so is there a big percentage of nulls in your table?

Comment: Are you experiencing any problems with the optimisers current plan? If not, why force it to do something it does not think is best? This is not a complex query ...

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting an index seek because you're fetching almost 93% of the rows in the table and in that kind of scenario, just scanning the whole index is faster and cheaper to do.

If you have performance issues, you should look into removing format() -function, especially if the query returns a lot of rows. Read [more from this blog post](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Other option might be to create an indexed view and pre-aggregate your data. This of course adds an overhead to update / insert operations, so consider that only if this is done really often vs. how often the table is updated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a UNION ALL?
select ...
Where isdeleted = 0
UNION ALL
select ... 
Where isdeleted is null

Or you can add an Query hint (index= [indexname])

also be aware that the cardinality will determine if SQL uses a seek or a scan - seeks are quicker but can require key lookups if the index doesnt cover all the columns required. A good rule of thumb is that if the query will return more than 5% of the table then SQL will prefer a scan.

Comment: Your first suggestion will cause the query to scan the table twice as mentioned by @RaduGheorghiu in the comments. Which would be expensive on performance if the table is large.

Comment: I've read posts which say that this rule of thumb only applies for 10% or more. Also, I've read posts that say that there is no "magic number" for this percentage. I tend to think that there is no magic number, since it will all be determined by query **cost**. And cost is more complex than *number of rows*. Yes, cardinality is important, but it's not the only factor.

Comment: @John: My table is growing on daily basis. Currently this table contains 0.5 million records. I would expect around 2 or 3 million.

Comment: @James: "null"=254962 rows, "0"=392002 rows, "1"=50211 rows