# Optimize SQL in MS SQL Server that returns more than 90% of records in the table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have the below sql

```
SELECT Cast(Format(Sum(COALESCE(InstalledSubtotal, 0)), 'F') AS MONEY) AS TotalSoldNet,
       BP.BoundProjectId                                               AS ProjectId
FROM   BoundProducts BP
WHERE  ( BP.IsDeleted IS NULL
          OR BP.IsDeleted = 0 )
GROUP  BY BP.BoundProjectId
```

I already have an index on the table BoundProducts on this column order (BoundProjectId, IsDeleted)

Currently this query takes around 2-3 seconds to return the result. I am trying to reduce it to zero seconds.

This query returns 25077 rows as of now.

Please provide me any ideas to improvise the query.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 25077 rows is quite a huge chunk of data. I don't think you might be able to tune this much further.

Comment: If i mention the filter condition as BP.IsDeleted=0 instead of (BP.IsDeleted is null or BP.IsDeleted=0). I can see there is an index seek but unfortunately I can't do this since I have records with null values too.

Comment: You're still fetching over 90% of the data? Like I said last time, scan is going to be faster than seek: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971763/performance-tuning-sql/32973346#32973346

Comment: Have you at least tried to remove format?

Comment: Yes but there is no luck, Is it possible to reduce the time, I am not bother about either index scan or index seek. My aim is to reduce its time.

Comment: @NewUser try also using COALESCE(BP.IsDeleted, 0) = 0 as single condition.

Comment: I tried with Isnull and Coalesce but no change in the execution plan

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this in a bit different point of view, I can think that your OR condition is screwing up your query, why not to rewrite it like this?

```
SELECT CAST(FORMAT(SUM(COALESCE(BP.InstalledSubtotal, 0)), 'F') AS MONEY) AS TotalSoldNet
    , BP.BoundProjectId AS ProjectId
FROM (
    SELECT BP.BoundProjectId, BP.InstalledSubtotal
    FROM dbo.BoundProducts AS BP
    WHERE BP.IsDeleted IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT BP.BoundProjectId, BP.InstalledSubtotal
    FROM dbo.BoundProducts AS BP
    WHERE BP.IsDeleted = 0
    ) AS BP
GROUP BY BP.BoundProjectId;
```

I've had better experience with `UNION ALL` rather than `OR`.

I think it should work totally the same. On top of that, I'd create this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_BoundProducts_IsDeleted_BoundProjectId_iInstalledSubTotal
    ON dbo.BoundProducts (IsDeleted, BoundProjectId)
    INCLUDE (InstalledSubTotal);
```

It should satisfy your query conditions and seek index quite well. I know it's not a good idea to index bit fields, but it's worth trying.

**P.S.** Why not to default your `IsDeleted` column value to 0 and make it `NOT NULLABLE`? By doing that, it should be enough to do a simple check `WHERE IsDeleted = 0`, that'd boost your query too.

Comment: if you write BP.IsDeleted <> 1 it will exclude the rows with NULL values

Comment: @Galma88 thanks for the spot, I've changed my answer, hopefully it's correct now.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to try index seek, it should be possible using query hint [forceseek](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510478%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but I don't think it's going to make it any faster.

The options I suggested [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971763/performance-tuning-sql/32973346#32973346) are still valid, remove format and / or create an indexed view.

You should also test if the problem is the query itself or just displaying the results after that, for example trying it with "select ... into #tmp". If that's fast, then the problem is not the query.

The index name in the screenshot is not the same as in create table statement, but I assume that's just a name you changed for the question. If the scan is happening to another index, then you should include that too.

Comment: I tried with Forceseek but I am getting the error "Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query...."

Comment: Maybe it works only in case of joins, and not if you're just fetching from a single table